# How to avoid type mismatch error with kotlin generic?

Tags: generics, kotlin

#### Code snippet

```
fun main() {
    val myClass : AbsClass<Any> = MyClass()
    // Error - type mismatch

    val myClass : AbsClass<*> = MyClass() 
    // Not Error, but parameter of 'foo' is 'Nothing'

    val myClass : AbsClass<Any> = MyClass() as AbsClass<Any> 
    // It's correct works with unchecked cast warning and unnecessary casting code.

    myClass.foo(MyModel())
}

class MyClass() : AbsClass<MyModel>() {
}

abstract class AbsClass<T> {
    fun foo(value:T){}
}

data class MyModel(val number:Int = 0)
```

#### Question

I want writing code as `val myClass : AbsClass<Any> = MyClass()` but, it shows type mismatch error. How to solve this problem(avoid type casting code`as AbsClass<Any>`)?

Comment: I think this is not possible as `foo` has `in` semantics. This only works if you can change `AbsClass<T>` to `AbsClass<out T>`

Comment: Not familiar with Kotlin, but I believe generics in Kotlin is similar to what in Java, which is not covariant.  i.e. `Foo<Derived>` is-not-a `Foo<Parent>`.  So you cannot assign a `AbsClass<MyModel>` instance to a `AbsClass<Any>` reference.

Comment: Actually generics in Kotlin **are** covariant, you can read more about that [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html)

Comment: @AlexanderEgger If you do that you can't use this `fun foo(value:T){}` IDE will complain saying `Type parameter T is declared as 'out' but occurs in 'in' position in type T AbsClass<out T>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use:

```
val myClass: AbsClass<out Any> = MyClass()` or `val myClass: AbsClass<in Nothing> = MyClass()
```

The `out` keyword means you want any subtype could be assigned to supertype. `MyModel` can by assigned to Any, so it's ok.

The `in` keyword means you expect any supertype could be assigned to subtype (in our case Nothing), so you can use your `MyModel` because it is the supertype of `Nothing`.

This way, without providing any information of expected type (you can specify, like `AbsClass<T : MyAbstractModel>`), in my opinion, there is really few possibilities without casting or reflection.

It's type variance and it's one of the most difficult ideas in OOP. More you can read here:
 https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance

Comment: Don't know why OP accepted your answer but it is wrong one. In both case you will get `Type mismatch. Required: Nothing, Found: MyModel` when you try to call this `myClass.foo(MyModel())`

Comment: Yep, but the question was about “how to declare”. That's why I have tried to explain later – using so wide type does not give a lot of possibilities.